# ServiseStack JwtAuthProvider

Tags: token, jwt

У нас есть готовый работающий проект `API` на `ServiceStack`. Авторизация через логин/пароль с помощью переопределенного `CredentialsAuthProvider`. Все работает. Сейчас потребовалось добавить `JWT`. Я добавил в конфиг `JwtAuthProvider`, но ничего не изменилось.

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
      new MobileAuthProvider(),
      new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
           HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
           PrivateKeyXml = AppSettings.GetString("PrivateKeyXml"),               
      }
 }) {
      HtmlRedirect = null
 });
```

Я не вижу `JWT` токенов в ответе сервера. Как их получить?

Answer (score 0):

Сам отвечаю. ошибка была совсем простой. Надо было разрешить провайдеру работать по http:

```
RequireSecureConnection = false
```

По умолчанию разрешается только https.